# Lebesgue integral over a ball

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

I want to ask about a result, which I do not know how to prove

Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Is it true that
$$\int_{B(x_0,1)} \dfrac{1}{|x|} dx \le \int_{B(0,1)} \dfrac{1}{|x|} dx?$$
Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Note that for any $x \in B(0,1)\backslash B(x_0,1)$ and $y \in B(x_0,1)\backslash B(0,1)$, you have $1/|y| \leq 1/|x|$.

Comment: But it seems that the integral on the right hand side is infinite...

Comment: @induction601 it's not. Its value is $2\pi$.

Comment: @Gribouillis. You realize that the domain of integration is the ball, including what's inside it, not just the surface?

Comment: Of course the integral on the right is finite! Integrate in polar coordinates: It's $c\int_01 (1/r) r^2\,dr$.

Comment: @Gribouillis You are right. Integral over a ball in $R^3$!

Comment: $\int_{B(0, 1)} |x|^\alpha dx$ converges in ${\mathbb R}^d$ iff $\alpha>-d$.

Comment: Typo, too late to edit: of course $\int_01$ was supposed to be $\int_0^1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. This is obvious, although it took me some time to see *why* it's obvious...

Let $A=B(0,1)\setminus B(x_0,1)$, $B=B(0,1)\cap B(x_0,1)$, $C=B(x_0,1)\setminus B(0,1)$. It's enough to show $$\int_A\frac1{|x|}\ge\int_C\frac1{|x|}.$$ And that's obvious because $\frac1{|x|}\ge1$ for $x\in A$ while $\frac1{|x|}\le 1$ for $x\in C$ (and of course $A$ and $C$ have the same measure).

Comment: I totally agree, I mean one can put it in polar coordinates and after some long computations be able to see it, but this seems so obvious that there is probably a faster way to see it. Nicely done!

Comment: That's why we should read comments because this idea was @induction601's first comment on this question.

Comment: @Gribouillis You're right. I missed the first part of that comment, distracted by the statement that the integral was infinite...

Comment: "This is obvious, but it took me a while to see why."  Heh.  I love mathematics. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a very smart solution. If $B:=B(0,1)$, $$ I(x_0) = \int_{B(x_0,r)}\frac{dx}{|x|} = \int_{B}\frac{dx}{|x-x_0|}$$
note that the gradient of a radial function is easy to compute by rewriting $\nabla$ in spherical coordinates: $\nabla = \frac{x}{r} \partial_r $. Hence, 
$$\nabla \frac{1}{|x|} = \left.\left(\partial_r \frac{1}{r}\right)\frac{x}{r} \right|_{r=|x|}=\frac{-x}{|x|^3}$$
Differentiation under the integral sign is permitted, and we obtain
$$\nabla I=\int_B\nabla_{x_0} \frac{1}{|x-x_0|}dx=\int_B \frac{x-x_0}{|x-x_0|^3} dx$$
For an arbitrary choice of the last 2 components of $x_0=(x^1_0,x^2_0,x^3_0)$, we can see that we only get a full cancellation in the first component if $x_0^1 = 0$. Repeating the analysis for each component, we see that $\nabla I = 0$ iff $x_0$ is the zero vector. Finally, note that for $|x_0|\gg 1$, $I(x_0)<I(0)$. Hence, $I$ is maximized at $0$.